# Find category-of-4 for number starting at 2

Tags: python-2.7

I'm tasked with categorizing numbers into groups with a range of four, starting at 2 (2, 6, 10, 14...). So for the number 9, the category would be 6 (between 6 and 10). I've developed the following function but I'm guessing there's a more efficient means and one that isn't limited in range.

```
>>> def FindCategory (num):
    categories = [2]
    lastVal = 2
    for i in range (100):
        lastVal = lastVal + 4
        categories += [lastVal]
    try:
        return [cat for cat in categories if cat < num and num < cat + 4] [0]
    except:
        return

>>> FindCategory (56)
54
>>> FindCategory (99999999999999999999999999)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use math?

```
def category(n):
    return (((n + 2) // 4) * 4) - 2
```

Examples:

```
>>> category(2)
2
>>> category(56)
54
>>> category(99)
98
>>> category(99999999999999999999999999)
99999999999999999999999998
```

By way of explanation: without the shift-by-2, you're just looking for the closest (lower) multiple of four, which can be found just by integer-division and then multiplication by 4 (i.e. `(n//4)*4`). The `+2` and `-2` account for the shift in your categories.